# htaccess mod rewrite non www to www and http to https IF site not accessed via IP address directly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We have a website that is currently accessed both via ip address and domain name, depending on the user.

If a user access the website via the domain name we need it to 301 redirect to the correct version (if it is accessed the non-correct way), eg:
301 redirect to, https://www.example.com (needs to be both www and https)

so if they access a page: https://example.com/page it will 301 redirect to https://www.example.com/page
if they access a page (without https) http://wwww.example.com/page it will 301 redirect to the https version of the page: https://www.example.com/page
and lastly if they d not have htts and do not have www it will redirect to the https and www version.

However if they access the site/page via the IP address directly (eg:`http://131.14.12.145/` - but this could technically change) it will not do any of the above redirects.

Any suggestions on how to set such up with htaccess rules?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
# (1) Redirect http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# (2) Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# (3) Direct access through IP
# CHANGE 11.11.11.11 TO YOUR ACTUAL IP
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^11\.11\.11\.11$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```